# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Mockito LocalDate and static method

Tags: spring-boot, static, mockito, telemetry

I'm using the Mockito 4.8.0 and Java 1.8 versions and I have a LocalDate variable which is sent to a static method where I get the error. The static method is to print logs using Telemetry.  Thanks in advance.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public class CategoryServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks    
    private ItemServiceImpl itemService;

    @Test public void getItem() { 
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 12); 
        itemService.getItem(startDate);    
    } 
}

public class ItemServiceImpl { 
    getItem(LocalDate  startDate){ 
        A.method(startDate); 
    } 
}

public class Utils {
    public static void method(final LocalDate startDate){} 
}
```

I tried to fix using mvn clean install and persists the problem. Please I appreciate any help or suggestion to solve it. This method works when it calls in other method.

Comment: Could you refactor to only have 1 public class in your file? I think it's a generally accepted Java principle to only have 1 public class per source file.

Comment: Actually, every class is located in different files. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is the `A` class in `A.method`?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, it must be Utils.

Comment: Why do you have `@InjectMocks` when your class does not have any dependencies?

Comment: I only copied the general flow of how it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to execute `CategoryServiceImplTest.java` successfully which is similar in nature to what you have in your question. Looks like you just need to tweak your code a little bit to get passed errors. I have java 8, spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.5 and junit 4.13.2 declared in my pom.xml. Your classes will most likely have differences than what I have below but this gives you an idea of how you can get passed your errors.

**CategoryService.java:**

```
package com.example.javalangnosuchmethoderror;

public interface CategoryService {
    String getCategory();
}
```

**CategoryServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.javalangnosuchmethoderror;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {
    @Override
    public String getCategory() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**ItemService.java**

```
package com.example.javalangnosuchmethoderror;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public interface ItemService {
    LocalDate getItem(LocalDate startDate);
}
```

**ItemServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.javalangnosuchmethoderror;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    @Override
    public LocalDate getItem(LocalDate startDate) {
        Utils.method(startDate);
        return startDate;
    }
}
```

**Utils.java**

```
package com.example.javalangnosuchmethoderror;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Utils {
    public static void method(final LocalDate startDate) {
    }
}
```

**CategoryServiceImplTest.java:**

```
package com.example.javalangnosuchmethoderror;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoryServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ItemServiceImpl itemService;

    @Test
    public void getItem() {
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 12, 12);
        itemService.getItem(startDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, everything was working well, the problem was about dependencies I used mvn dependency:purge-local-repository. Your approach works well.